# COMO FAÇO PARA SELECIONAR UMA DIV COM PHP?

Tags: php, html, div

Estou preso em um exercício no seguinte exercício.

> Crie um loop com `do...while` que exiba dentro de um elemento `<div>` o índice atual, porém quando o índice de repetição for 2, 6 e 10, troque a cor de fundo apenas desta div. O loop começa de 0 e vai até 12.

Eu consegui criar o loop, porém, estou preso na parte de colorir as divs nas posições citadas no exercicio. Vou por o codigo abaixo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DoWhile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>  
        <?php
        $indice = 0; 
        do {
        ?>
        <div id="box" style="height:100px; width:500px; background-color:gray; margin-bottom:5px;" >
            <? = $indice;?>             
        </div>
        <?php
        $indice++;
        }
        while ($indice <= 12);
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso sem depender de vários `IF ELSE` pra cada situação, seria guardando cada estilo em um `array` e durante o *loop*, verificar se existe a chave no `array` com o valor atual da `$indice`, caso contrário, aplique o estilo padrão.

Dessa forma, você poderia somente adicionar novos estilos dentro do `array`, sem necessidade de criar nenhuma nova condição dentro do loop.

Por exemplo:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DoWhile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    
        $styles['default'] = "gray";
        $styles[2] = "yellow";
        $styles[6] = "red";
        $styles[10] = "blue";
        
        $indice = 0; 
        do {
        $style = $styles[$indice] ?? $styles['default'];
        ?>
        <div id="box" style="height:100px; width:500px; background-color:<?=$style?>; margin-bottom:5px;">
            <?= $indice;?>             
        </div>
        <?php
        $indice++;
        }
        while ($indice <= 12);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[Teste aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1662a5c930d0281990cc9c70c27ea648908fae67)

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é separar o estilo da marcação em um arquivo de *CSS* então para decidir qual `<div>` colorir com que cor.

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Para isso basta, com auxilio do [operador condicional ternário](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), alterar a classe do elemento baseado no resultado da função [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php) que retorna `true` caso um valor esteja contido num array especificado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DoWhile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="{NOME DO ARQUIVO CSS}.css"-->
</head>
<body>  
        <?php
        $indice = 0; 
        do {
        ?>
        <div id="box" class="<?= in_array($indice,[2,6,10])? 'red': 'gray'; ?>">
            <?= $indice;?>             
        </div>
        <?php
        $indice++;
        }
        while ($indice <= 12);
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

O que resulta em:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DoWhile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="{NOME DO ARQUIVO CSS}.css"-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    0
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="red">
    2
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    3
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    4
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    5
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="red">
    6
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    7
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    8
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    9
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="red">
    10
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    11
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="gray">
    12
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Também como sugerido nos comentários é possível atribuir a classe a ser estilizada apenas quando a condição for atendida:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DoWhile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="{NOME DO ARQUIVO CSS}.css"-->
</head>
<body>  
        <?php
        $indice = 0; 
        do {
        ?>
        <div id="box" <?= in_array($indice,[2,6,10])? 'class="red"':''; ?>>
            <?= $indice;?>             
        </div>
        <?php
        $indice++;
        }
        while ($indice <= 12);
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultando em:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DoWhile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="{NOME DO ARQUIVO CSS}.css"-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box">
    0
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="red">
    2
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    3
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    4
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    5
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="red">
    6
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    7
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    8
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    9
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="red">
    10
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    11
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    12
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Uma sugestão nessa forma, seria remover a classe `.gray` e adicionar ao estilo padrão da classe `div`, aplicando apenas as classes alternativas quando forem acionadas.

Comment: @WeslleyAraújo, as orientações foram incorporadas a resposta. Obrigado.