# Mudar cor de texto em tabela no PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Na minha tabela, tenho a coluna "Concluída?" que apresenta apenas duas informações: "Sim" e "Não", gostaria de alterar as cores dos textos, verde para Sim e vermelho para Nã?

Segue parte do código:

```
 <div class="box3">

        <table class="table">

            <thead>

                <tr>

                    <th class="margem" scope="col">#</th>

                    <th class="margem" scope="col">Resumo</th>

                    <th class="margem" scope="col">Descrição</th>

                    <th class="margem" scope="col">Concluida?</th>

                    <th class="margem" scope="col">Data</th>

                    <th class="margem" scope="col">Atribuído</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>

 

                <?php

                    while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))

                    {

                        echo "<tr>";

                        echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['idDemandas']."</td>";

                        echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Resumo']."</td>";

                        echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Descricao']."</td>";

                        echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Conclusao']."</td>";

                        echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Data_Post']."</td>";

                        echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Atribuido']."</td>";

                        echo "<td>

                        <a href='editDem.php?idDemandas=$user_data[idDemandas]' class='edt'><img class='edt' id='edt' src='http://pi01pa1350.almavivadobrasil.com.br/dennys/Site%203/Img_menu/lapis.gif' alt='Editar'></a>

                        <a href='DeleteDem.php?idDemandas=$user_data[idDemandas]' class='edt'><img class='edt' id='edt' src='http://pi01pa1350.almavivadobrasil.com.br/dennys/Site%203/Img_menu/lixo.gif' alt='Editar'></a>

                        </td>";

                        echo "</tr>";

                    }

                ?>

            </tbody>

        </table>

 

    </div>
```

Comment: Veja alguma das respostas o ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/500297/137387

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema com uma simples edição em um dos td, segue código editado caso alguém precise:

```
    <table class="table">

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th class="margem" scope="col">#</th>

                <th class="margem" scope="col">Resumo</th>

                <th class="margem" scope="col">Descrição</th>

                <th class="margem" scope="col">Concluida?</th>

                <th class="margem" scope="col">Data</th>

                <th class="margem" scope="col">Atribuído</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>



            <?php

                while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))

                {?>

                    <tr>

       



                 <? echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['idDemandas']."</td>";

                    echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Resumo']."</td>";

                    echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Descricao']."</td>";?>

                    <td <?php if($user_data['Conclusao'] == "Sim"){?> style="color:chartreuse"<?}?> <?php if($user_data['Conclusao'] == "Não"){?> style="color:red" <?}?> <?php echo "<td class='margem' id='cor'>".$user_data['Conclusao']."</td>"?></td>

                    <?php

                    echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Data_Post']."</td>";

                    echo "<td class='margem'>" .$user_data['Atribuido']."</td>";

                    echo "<td>

                    <a href='editDem.php?idDemandas=$user_data[idDemandas]' class='edt'><img class='edt' id='edt' src='http://pi01pa1350.almavivadobrasil.com.br/dennys/Site%203/Img_menu/lapis.gif' alt='Editar'></a>

                    <a href='DeleteDem.php?idDemandas=$user_data[idDemandas]' class='edt'><img class='edt' id='edt' src='http://pi01pa1350.almavivadobrasil.com.br/dennys/Site%203/Img_menu/lixo.gif' alt='Editar'></a>

                    </td>";

                    echo "</tr>";

                }

            ?>



        </tbody>

    </table>

   

</div>
```